# How to select a time in flutters time picker from integration test

Tags: flutter, android-timepicker

I'm writing an integration test for a flutter app where I need to open the time picker and select a time, Its a time picker dialog in android, I can tap the time above the picker and tap the ok and cancel buttons but I cannot change the selected time for the dial. Looking at their widget test they're testing it using an offset which I'm not sure how to do this from an integration test. I've created a demo and took a screenshot of the flutter widget tree where you can see the dial and gesture detector etc but there aren't any keys to find and trying to find by text isn't possible either, digging into the source code they create a list of _TappableLabel which gets the text from the painter, does anyone have a way to do this?

[image: flutter widget tree]

Comment: did you manage to solve this in the meantime perhaps?

Comment: no i never did i think i was trying to do something like 
await tester.assertType('CustomPaint', 'Time Picker', sublabels: labels);
await driver.waitFor(find.descendant(of: find.byType('TextPainter'), matching: find.text('11')));            //the assert type method is just a custom matcher, the other uses flutter driver

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inspired from the timepicker unit test, thats doable that way :

```dart
    var center = tester
        .getCenter(find.byKey(const ValueKey<String>('time-picker-dial')));

    await tester.tapAt(Offset(center.dx - 10, center.dy));
```

Since the dial accept clicking close to the center, the 10 offset is enough to select 9 in that case.

Comment: this is beautiful and horrible at the same time  i really hope there is a better answer at some point but congrats on getting something working

Comment: Me too, but since the datepicker unit test is somehow made that way, I can of doubt it... Besides, I would not do something like it in actual code, but for testing code, that's kind of OK...

Answer (score 0):

I am doing that from within the flutter driver test but the implementation of the command is done as a part of my own driver extension and can be used in your integration test (you just replace my ***prober*** with your ***tester***)

```
    final finder = find
        .ancestor(
            of: find.byKey(const ValueKey('time-picker-dial')),
            matching: find.byType(Listener))
        .first;
    // Wait for the time picker dialog
    await handlerFactory.waitForElement(finder).timeout(command.timeout!,
        onTimeout: () => throw ("Failed to find the time picker dialog"));
    final hoursAngleDeg = command.hours * 360 / 12;
    final minutesAngleDeg = command.minutes * 360 / 60;
    final center = prober.getCenter(finder);
    final topRight = prober.getTopRight(finder);
    final radius = topRight.dx - center.dx;
    final tapAtHours = Offset(
        center.dx + radius * cos((hoursAngleDeg - 90) * pi / 180),
        center.dy + radius * sin((hoursAngleDeg - 90) * pi / 180));
    final tapAtMinutes = Offset(
        center.dx + radius * cos((minutesAngleDeg - 90) * pi / 180),
        center.dy + radius * sin((minutesAngleDeg - 90) * pi / 180));
    await prober.tapAt(tapAtHours);
    await handlerFactory.waitForElement(finder).timeout(command.timeout!,
        onTimeout: () =>
            throw ("Failed to find the minutes time picker dialog"));
    await prober.tapAt(tapAtMinutes);
```